# How to determine a Point of a parallogram if three points is given

Tags: linear-algebra

Given
$$A= (0,0,1), \ B= (−1,1,3), \ D= (2,1,−1).$$

I need to find the coordinates of the point $C$ so that $ABCD$ is a parallelogram.

I think to determin AB for example you take:
Point $A$ - Point $B\Rightarrow (0,0,1) - (-1,1,3) \Rightarrow (1,-1,-2)$?

But how do I determine the Point $C=(x, y, z)$?

Is it like Point $D$ - Point $C\Rightarrow (2,1,-1) -(x,y,z) \Rightarrow (2-x,1-y,-1-z)$?

After that I get stuck.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have$$AB=B-A=(-1,1,3)-(0,0,1)=(-1,1,2).$$So, in order to get a parallelogram take $C=D+AB$. So,$$C=(2,1,-1)+(-1,1,2)=(1,2,1).$$

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Jose Carlos Santos Why is it C + AB = D?

Comment: Because that's what you need in order the get a parallelogram; take a look at the picture that I've added to my answer.